# Nginx - hide .php extension and use language arguments in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, nginx, url-rewriting

I currently have a url `http://www.goo.com/about.php?lang=cn` and wants to rewrite as `http://www.goo.com/about?lang=cn`

I tried as follows:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri?$lang=arg_lang
}
```

But somehow doesn't work.

I tried accessing `http://www.goo.com/about` which works. But, whenever I pass an argument as `http://www.goo.com/about?lang=cn` doesn't seem to work.

I have also found that the above rule works with `http://www.goo.com/about.php?lang=cn` .

I basically wants to hide `.php` and use arguments in the url

Answer (score 0):

You have use this rule for your rewrite to work the way you want it.

```
location / {
if ($query_string ~ "(^|&)lang=cn($|&)"){
rewrite ^/about\.php$ /about?lang=cn&$query_string;
}
}
```